# Extract the URL from a hyperlink in a textview

Tags: android, url, textview

How would I go about extracting a URL from a hyperlink when I click on it? There could be more than one URL link in the body of the text.

Comment: What you want to do by clicking on a text with multiple URLs?

Comment: I have to read in the URL and basically get the id?=123123 out of it, and there are 3 or 4 different formats of the URL. one is www.abcxyz.com/id?=123123 or www.abcxyz.com/aricle/news/123123.
Similar to that. So... I have to extract the URL text and run it through a function to get the id off of it.

Comment: Is this something you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11101507/regular-expression-to-get-url-collection-from-string

Comment: no.. i dont think that will work

Answer (score 3):

If I get your question correctly, so have different URL's in the text of your `TextView` and you want to extract them first. Then you want to extract the parameters from each URL's. I think you are looking for something like [getUrls()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getUrls%28%29) function in TextView. Here is how you can extract the URL's present in your textview:

```
URLSpan spans[] = textView.getUrls();
for(URLSpan span: spans) {
    String sampleUrl = span.getURL();
    Log.d(TAG, sampleUrl);
}
```

Using this you can get different URL's in form of String. Then using [.split()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732790/android-split-string) function you can extract the query parameter.

See [get Linkified text from textview-android...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11735725/get-linkified-text-from-textview-android) question for more.

Hope this helps.